# symfony embed Ajax field in form

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony

In symfony I have a Cliente entity that can have N Reservas:

```
class Cliente {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Reserva", mappedBy="cliente")
     * 
     */
    private $reservas;
....
}

class Reserva
{   

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cliente", inversedBy="reservas")
     * 
     */
    private $cliente;
...}
```

In the ReservaType I have:

```
class ReservaType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('cliente')               
            ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'partes\EscuelaBundle\Entity\Reserva'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'partes_escuelabundle_reserva';
    }

}
```

All that when I create a new reserva show my the typical select option with the list of all customers. I would change that  for a ajax input type to select the customer. Any idea how to build it.
Thanks you!

Comment: And what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

fix it, with a ajax call that bring a list of links. Once clicking in the link it creates the new Reserva.